# Pascal Why won't this simple random range work?

Tags: pascal

Trying to get a number in the range of a (variable -2) and (variable +2).
For example, if X = 7, then i would like a random number generator that gives a value in the range 5 - 9.  See below my attempt which gives me unexpected results:

```
var x, xRange, i,count,xLower, xhigher:integer;
begin
  x:=7;
  xLower:=x-2;
  xHigher:=x+2;

  for count:= 1 to 20 do
  begin
    i:=random(xHigher)+xLower;
    writeln(i);
  end;
readln;
end.
```

Comment: I think you want `i:=random(xHigher-xLower)+xLower;`.

Comment: Should not you have used  `i:=random(xHigher-xLower)+xLower;`?

Comment: Use Randomize before calling Random: [Random](http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/rtl/system/random.html). 

This way you will actually get random numbers on each run.

Answer (score 1):

As was mentioned by the [user 500 - Internal Server Error](https://stackoverflow.com/users/448932/500-internal-server-error) and [Marat Talipov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1898580/marat-talipov)

you want:

```
i:=random(xHigher-xLower)+xLower;
```

You should also use the `Randomize;` call before you call Random so that you get a new random value each time. So in the end:

```
var x, xRange, i,count,xLower, xhigher:integer;
begin
  Randomize;
  x:=7;
  xLower:=x-2;
  xHigher:=x+2;

  for count:= 1 to 20 do
  begin
    i:=random(xHigher-xLower)+xLower;
    writeln(i);
  end;
readln;
end.
```

Comment: You call Randomize **once** at the start of the program.  Calling it inside the loop like this is a very bad idea.  You're not going to get random numbers out of your code!

Comment: changed the Randomize because you are correct. Otherwise the program works